# How to access a table's particular cell when you know the row number

Tags: sapui5

I have a table with 3 columns, one of the columns is a checkbox, one is taking input and third one is simple text. Whenever a person enters a value in the input I want to make the checkbox of that row selected. Following is the way I am extracting input entered.

```js
inputChange: function(oEvent) {
  var a = oEvent.getSource();
  var input = a.getValue();
  var row = oEvent.getSource().getParent().getParent();
  var index = row.getIndex();
  // ...
}
```

I have the row index but I do not know how to traverse to the checkbox box of that row and make the checkbox selected. How to frame that syntax?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of iterating through the list of cells or accessing a row via multiple `getParent` calls, try with [expression binding](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0):

```xml
<CheckBox selected="{= !!${myModel>thatInputValue}}" />
```

Binding allows us to separate data from the UI structure (loose coupling). The framework will take care of updating the `selected` value when `thatInputValue` in the model gets updated (which can be done either via two-way data binding or via `myModel.setProperty`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one(not very efficient) way of doing it which is close to what you are trying.
However, I recommend Boghyon's solution as a good practice.

```js
1. Get the row Index you are working on

var rowIndex = oEvent.getSource().getParent().getBindingContextPath().split("/")[2];    <--- split this code into multiple lines if does not work in one. 


2. Get the checkBox control of the selected Row using the table.

var oChewckBox = this.getView().byId("TableId").getAggregation("items")[rowIndex].getAggregation("cells")[0<this should be the column number in your table>]

3.  Make the checkBox Selected.

oCheckBox.setSelected(false)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create a property that the checkbox is bound to in the XML.

Then you can use this code to set the property to either true or false on button click.

```
        var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
        var sRow = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext().getPath();
        oModel.setProperty(sRow + "/checked", TRUE OR FALSE HERE);
```

Please let me know if you need any help with the property binding.  It was hard for me to explain that part without seeing more code.